# Creating an alias in Powershell that includes a space (for a parameter)

Tags: windows, powershell, alias

I want to start the control panel applet `RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL` via an alias in PowerShell. Running it directly works fine but when I set an alias:

```
set-Alias controlpanel "RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL"
```

and execute it, I get the standard error message `The term 'RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,...(snip)`

I figured out that this is due to the space in between the runDLL.exe and shell.dll. Is it possible to add alias with the space somehow?

Comment: the `Set-Alias` cmdlet is for making an alias to a single & simple thing. if you want to use something more than just that - like a macro - you will need to make a function that contains the desired complex command & either create an alias for that with the `Set-Alias` cmdlet OR use the `[Alias()]` attribute in the function definition.  [*grin*]

Comment: Thx I figured that out already (see my answer)

Comment: yep, i saw that ... just wanted to add a different way to state the same thing & mention the `[Alias()]` attribute inside the function can have the same effect as `Set-Alias`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an alias allows for another name for [one ("single") command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291583/powershell-whats-the-difference-between-alias-and-function). So in a way it's understandable that this does not include parameters. (Although I'm not sure why PowerShell doesn't parse the second string as a parameter anyway are there any 2 words commands?)

The solution is to use a function which in my case would be `Function controlpanel { RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL }`.

Answer (score 0):

> You must create a function that contains the command with parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-aliases?view=powershell-7.3#creating-alternate-names-for-commands-with-parameters